# Iterating over joined query data in Laravel Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-10

Categories and courses are two tables. Based on Category, an 'n' number of data can be inserted into the course. While fetching the API response, it should be like below.

**Controller**

```
public function catlist($catid)
{
    $category = 
    DB::table('courses')
    ->join('categories', 'courses.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')// joining the Categories table , where category_id and categories id are same
    ->select(
    'categories.id as catid',
    'categories.name as catname',
    'courses.id as courseid',
    'courses.title as coursename'
    )
    ->where('courses.category_id', '=', $catid)
    ->get();

    foreach ($category as $cat) 
    {
        $data = [
            'category'=>[
                "id" => $cat->catid,
                "name" => $cat->catname,
                ],
            'courselist'=>[
                "id" => $cat->courseid,
                "name" => $cat->coursename,
            ]
        ];
    }
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $data,
    ],200);
}
```

The actual result is:

```
  "data": {
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test Category"
    },

    "courseList": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Course 2"
    }
}
```

Expected results will be:

```
data=[
    category: {
      id: 1,
      name: "Test Category"
      },

      courseList: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Course 1",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Course 2",
      },
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself after doing a lot of search. Now it is working now.

```
   $category = DB::table('categories')->where('id', $catid)->first();
    // Retrieve course list
    $courseList = DB::table('courses')->whereIn('category_id', [$catid])->get();

    if ($category === null) 
    {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'No such a Category',
        ], 404);
    }else{
        // Construct the response array
        $data = [
            'category' => $category,
            'courseList' => $courseList,
        ];
    
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $data,
        ],200);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you have is returning a row for each course and category, you should use either normal laravel relationships, or you need to use the sql groupBy categories.id method on your query.

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships